# While filing visa application for Turkey do I need to provide my transit visa for Dubai stay which is scheduled on my return leg of the trip

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, turkey, dubai

I plan to visit Turkey from India. I will be traveling via Dubai (Emirates). On my return to India I plan to stay 2-3 days in Dubai.

Do I need to show my Dubai transit visa while applying for Turkey visa to the consulate even though it will be on my return trip since I will be staying in Dubai for 2-3 days on my return trip from Turkey to India?

I will only stay in Dubai while returning from Turkey, not while flying to turkey.

I am trying to ascertain that when I apply for the Turkey visa the consulate doesn't end up asking my Dubai transit visa .

I was planning not to apply for Dubai transit visa until I get the Turkey visa stamped to ensure I don't waste my money in case the Turkey visa gets rejected for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to show your Dubai visa as it does not have any bearing on your application for the Turkish visa. In fact, as you don't need a visa to transit through Dubai (unless you are switching airports - or in your case, having a layover), it wouldn't matter to the Turkish authorities.